# TypeError in Azure OpenAI with Python package: Unexpected keyword argument 'organization

Tags: python, typeerror, openai-api, azure-openai

I am trying to use the openai Python package to interact with the Azure OpenAI API. I have written the following code:

```
import os
import openai

openai.api_type = "azure"
openai.api_base = "pseudo_base"
openai.api_version = "2023-03-15-preview"
openai.api_key = "pseudo_key"

response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
  engine="gpt-35-turbo",
  messages = [{"role":"system","content":"You are an AI assistant that helps people find information."},{"role":"user","content":"hello"}],
  temperature=0.7,
  max_tokens=800,
  top_p=0.95,
  frequency_penalty=0,
  presence_penalty=0,
  stop=None
)
```

I simply get the following error:

```
openai\api_resources\abstract\engine_api_resource.py:106, in EngineAPIResource.__prepare_create_request(cls, api_key, api_base, api_type, api_version, organization, **params)
    103 elif timeout == 0:
    104     params["timeout"] = MAX_TIMEOUT
--> 106 requestor = api_requestor.APIRequestor(
    107     api_key,
    108     api_base=api_base,
    109     api_type=api_type,
    110     api_version=api_version,
    111     organization=organization,
    112 )
    113 url = cls.class_url(engine, api_type, api_version)
    114 return (
    115     deployment_id,
    116     engine,
   (...)
    124     params,
    125 )

TypeError: APIRequestor.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'organization'
```

I would think the APIRequestor class would handle it all for me as I've already declared the type to be "azure". Any good ideas before I fork and adjust the entire openai package to fit to Azure OpenAI?

The OpenAI package works perfectly fine when I'm simply using my private OpenAI key.

EDIT:
My deployment name is similar to the engine name

```
openai=0.27.6
python=3.11.3
```

Comment: Have you set engine to be your deployment name, rather than model name?

Comment: I forgot to mention they’re similar. Thank you for mentioning it.

Comment: what version of python and openai package are you using? I can't recreate the error with `python=3.9.16` and `openai=0.27.2` - might be worth giving them a shot.

Comment: I added the information to the main question. I'm running openai 0.27.6 and python 3.11.3

Comment: I'd test creating a new virtual environment, maybe with the versions I list above - looks like a package conflict problem but not sure...

Comment: If this is the key blocker and virtual env isn't working, this is what I would look into; a) If you go into the engine_api_resource.py file and `print(organization)` whats printed? For me it's `None; None`. b) Go into the api_requestor.py file, see what the class `APIRequestor` init takes. eg. If organization is there c) If you go to `openai /__init__.py` you will see that `organization=os.environ.get("OPENAI_ORGANISATION")` which in my case is used in the APIRequestor class, returning None (as the environment variable is not set, nor is it passed to the class) -> TLDR; Check your env variable